# Laravel 5.4 invalid request (unexpected eof)

Tags: php, laravel, url, artisan

Здравствуйте. Делаю свой небольшой блог. Возникла проблемка с переходами по url. Для создания и редактирования постов создала контроллер PostController. Так вот. У меня неправильно отрабатывают все методы контроллера, кроме @index. Когда пытаюсь зайти по url **http://localhost:8000/admin/post/create** artisan мне выдает ошибку 
**invalid request (unexpected eof)**, хотя такой путь существует. Метод как бы отрабатывает, страница рендерится, но выдается пользователю без маломальских стилей. Вот так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно быть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прикрепляю еще список роутов, которые задействованы и ошибку, которую выдает мне сервер.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рада любой помощи.

Comment: А в исходном коде как выглядит путь до стилей?

Comment: Попробуйте еще запустить команду php artisan cache:clear.

Comment: Спасибо. Проблему решила уже. Действительно были проблемы с путем к стилям.